# Show library file in solution explorer

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I don't know if this is possible in Visual Studio, but in Eclipse I can go to the declaration of a method i.e. the `asList()` method. 
[image]

Now if we go to the declaration it shows that it's from the Arrays.class library file. And in the image below it also shows the library file in package explorer as well.[image]

In Visual Studio I had tried the same with the `IsDevelopment()` method.[image]

However Visual Studio doesn't shows the library file in solution explorer. As you can see in the image below.[image]

In Visual Studio I have already tried to check the option "Track Active Item in Solution Explorer" to turn that feature on. But it doesn't work for library files.

Comment: but the top of the window it says `Assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstraction` isn't it enough for the information about the library?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know if this is possible in Visual Studio

No, While you don't have the library source code and just have access to compiled version(dll) file you can't move to its source code.

In visual studio you can just see the `meta data` info for each function/class by pressing `F12` on its name. But if you have the library source code in current project/solution you can jump to its code.

But if you still want to see the `dll` files source code, you are better off with a decompiler like redgates .net reflector or jetbrains resharper decompiler. there are open source ones also like:

http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/

http://ilspy.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can only view the source code for assemblies that you have the source code of. Since you don't have the source code for that, only the compiled version, you can only see the metadata. You could decompile the source code to bring it back to C#, but that wouldn't be the original source code and would be much harder to read.

Thankfully in this particular case, you're dealing with ASP.NET Core which is open source, with the code hosted on GitHub. The original source code for [HostingEnvironmentExtensions](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions/HostingEnvironmentExtensions.cs) is available there.

If you want to see the source code for an assembly that you don't have the source code, ask yourself: "is this open source?". If it is, then go find where it's hosted.

Comment: Is it also possible to import the source code into Visual Studio? Because I can't open other library files (because it's metadata) that I see in the solution explorer.

Comment: @superkytoz You saw the code on GitHub right? You know how to clone a repository? Then you know how to add an existing project into your solution?

Comment: I only don't know how to add it to an existing project into the solution. If you want to explain it, I gladly want to receive your explanation.

Comment: You add the project to your solution, then add a reference to it from your original project.

Comment: It worked partially. It went to the source code of `IHostingEnvironment` interface when I had my cursor on the reference type of the `env` variable. However when my cursor was on `IsDevelopment()` method. Then I couldn't go to the declaration. Because I had received a pop up  “Cannot navigate to the symbol under the caret.”. So I have removed the source code from the project.